# JPA Multiple Queries on join

Tags: java, jpa

In this specific scenario, say I have a couple of tables {A,B} and their generated JPA classes. There is a FK relationship on a column X from Table A -> Table B and this column X in Table A has been annotated with

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "X", referencedColumnName = "X", insertable = false, updatable = false).
```

I have a Named JPA Query which is joining the two tables on this column "X". On execution, I get the correct results,but multiple queries are being run against the DB. On 
the join's each data match, it appears a query is being generated and run against the DB. This is overburdening our Database. From my understanding, on a LAZY fetch, isn't JPA supposed to execute the master query only once and bring back the entire result-set, instead of spawning additional child queries for join's data match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do a join query to get the data. If you specify `OneToOne`, Hibernate associates the two objects. `LAZY` means that the request to get the linked object will only be launched when you **need** that object.